# How to delete written text in above lines in C?

Tags: c, string, cmd

I'm programming at C and wondered about that.
let's say there's this simple program:

```
Username:
Password:
```

Now... It looks simple and it is simple to print and all (`printf("Username: \nPassword: ");`)
but how do I get the username string ? fgets of course but... I want the user type it right after the "Username: " and not after the password. you can preform `printf("\b");` to delete previously written data **in the same line** but how can I reach to the "Username: " ? "\b" is no useful after it deletes the "Password:", same for carriage return obviously. How do I do that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: you can disply `"Username:"` , then input username and display it . Then after that same for password.

Comment: Look at what I said to story teller...

Comment: +@vladLazarenko - no emulator - simple CMD, gcc and notepad++.

Comment: "CMD" suggests you are writing a command line utility. Command line utilities are not supposed to write up and down the screen -- ideally, you should be able to redirect both input and output. As soon as you are trying to circumvent the one-line at a time paradigm, you might as well use a full GUI.

Comment: @Jongware "TUI" is a fine UI paradigm, if slightly outdated (though there are counter-examples to outdatedness, such as *irssi*, one of the best IRC clients). CMD terminal window resembles more closely MS-DOS text mode (with direct control of screen contents) than Unix terminal (which runs on top of a char stream).

Comment: There are a lot of details to manage when using this form of entry... If you still wish to do it this way, I urge you to give [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net) a chance. Managing this stuff on your own will both give you some good Windows API experience and make you waste time focusing on the little things for which a relatively standard library already can do. It is up to you how to proceed, but I really do think you're better off using PDCurses.

Answer (score 3):

If this is Windows, you can move the cursor like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void setCursorPos(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hStdout;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout, &csbiInfo);
    csbiInfo.dwCursorPosition.X = x;
    csbiInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout, csbiInfo.dwCursorPosition);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    system("cls");
    char user[128], pass[128];
    printf("Username:\r\nPassword:\r\n");
    setCursorPos(10, 0);
    fgets(user, 128, stdin);
    setCursorPos(10, 1);
    fgets(pass, 128, stdin);
    printf("User = %s, Pass = %s\r\n", user, pass);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try terminal escape sequences described for example [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) and supported by majority of terminals. They allow moving of the cursor on the screen and similar effects. Check the following code if it is a good starting point for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Username: \nPassword: \n");
    printf("\033[2A\033[10C");  // move cursor 2 lines up, 10 chars right.
    fflush(stdout);
    getchar();
    // ... continue your reading, moving, ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char username[64];
    char password[16];
    int ch, i = 0;

    printf("Username:");
    scanf("%63[^\n]%*c", username);
    printf("Password:");

    while((ch=getch())!='\r' && i < 16-1){
        putchar('*');
        password[i++]= ch;
    }
    password[i] = '\0';
    if(strcmp(password, "drowssap")==0)
        printf("\nOK\n>");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe just

```
printf("Username:");
/* do stuff */
printf("Password:");
/* do stuff */
```

Comment: Nope. I want it like I said, them both and then enter, I'm almost 100% sure it's possible :P

Comment: @user3220493, good luck with that, if you ask out of curiosity. Otherwise, enjoy bashing your head against the table.